# How to establish Oracle Anonymous data warehouse ODBC connection with Microstrategy

Tags: oracle, odbc, cloud, microstrategy, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

Need to confirm host name, port ,Service, TNS etc to connect Microstrategy host on AWS Cloud.

Answer (score 0):

Not a Microstrategy expert, but from the research it appears that they're using ODBC drivers for connection to Oracle databases.

You can reuse this documentation that's showing how to connect to ADW with Progress odbc:
[Connecting to Autonomous Data Warehouse with Progress DataDirect ODBC Driver](https://www.oracle.com/a/ocom/docs/database/datadirect-connection-adw.pdf)